# Shell Script Invocation Error Command /bin/sh failed with exit

Tags: objective-c

i am trying to make framework for third party in ios for iphone.when i build my project i got an error that error is Shell Script Invocation Error Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

my Shell Script is-

```
set -e

mkdir -p "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A"

mkdir -p "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/Headers"



# Link the "Current" version to "A"

ln -sf A "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/Current"

ln -sf Versions/Current/Headers "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Headers"

ln -sf "Versions/Current/${PRODUCT_NAME}" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/${PRODUCT_NAME}"



# The -a ensures that the headers maintain the source modification date so that we don't constantly

# cause propagating rebuilds of files that import these headers.
cp -a "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH}/" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/Headers"
```

and my error is-

```
PhaseScriptExecution Prepare_Framework.sh "\"/Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos\"  \"/Users/manoj/Desktop/Serenity/..\""
    setenv FRAMEWORK_VERSION A
    setenv FULL_PRODUCT_NAME libSerenity.a
    setenv GCC3_VERSION 3.3
    setenv GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD gnu99
    setenv GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC NO
    setenv GCC_ENABLE_SSE42_EXTENSIONS YES
    setenv GCC_ENABLE_SYMBOL_SEPARATION NO
    setenv GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL 0
    setenv GCC_PFE_FILE_C_DIALECTS "c objective-c c++ objective-c++"
    setenv GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER YES
    setenv GCC_PREFIX_HEADER Serenity/Serenity-Prefix.pch
    setenv GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS "DEBUG=1 "
    setenv GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN NO
    setenv GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT YES
    setenv GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS NO
    setenv GCC_VERSION com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
    setenv GCC_VERSION_IDENTIFIER com_apple_compilers_llvm_clang_1_0
    setenv GCC_WARN_ABOUT_MISSING_PROTOTYPES YES
    setenv GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE YES
    setenv GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VARIABLE YES
    setenv GENERATE_MASTER_OBJECT_FILE NO
    setenv GENERATE_PKGINFO_FILE NO
    setenv GENERATE_PROFILING_CODE NO
    setenv GID 20
    setenv GROUP staff
    setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FLAT_ENTRIES_FOR_TARGET_BEING_BUILT YES
    setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FRAMEWORK_ENTRIES_FOR_ALL_PRODUCT_TYPES YES
    setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_NONPUBLIC_NONPRIVATE_HEADERS YES
    setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_PROJECT_HEADERS YES
    setenv HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS "\"/Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include\" "
    setenv ICONV /usr/bin/iconv
    setenv INFOPLIST_EXPAND_BUILD_SETTINGS YES
    setenv INFOPLIST_OUTPUT_FORMAT binary
    setenv INFOPLIST_PREPROCESS NO
    setenv INSTALL_DIR /tmp/Serenity.dst/usr/local/lib
    setenv INSTALL_GROUP staff
    setenv INSTALL_MODE_FLAG u+w,go-w,a+rX
    setenv INSTALL_OWNER manoj
    setenv INSTALL_PATH /usr/local/lib
    setenv INSTALL_ROOT /tmp/Serenity.dst
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
    setenv JAVAC_DEFAULT_FLAGS "-J-Xms64m -J-XX:NewSize=4M -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"
    setenv JAVA_APP_STUB /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
    setenv JAVA_ARCHIVE_CLASSES YES
    setenv JAVA_ARCHIVE_TYPE JAR
    setenv JAVA_COMPILER /usr/bin/javac
    setenv JAVA_FRAMEWORK_RESOURCES_DIRS Resources
    setenv JAVA_JAR_FLAGS cv
    setenv JAVA_SOURCE_SUBDIR .
    setenv JAVA_USE_DEPENDENCIES YES
    setenv JAVA_ZIP_FLAGS -urg
    setenv JIKES_DEFAULT_FLAGS "+E +OLDCSO"
    setenv KEEP_PRIVATE_EXTERNS NO
    setenv LD_GENERATE_MAP_FILE NO
    setenv LD_MAP_FILE_PATH /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Intermediates/Serenity.build/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.build/Serenity-LinkMap-normal-armv7.txt
    setenv LD_NO_PIE NO
    setenv LD_OPENMP_FLAGS -fopenmp
    setenv LEGACY_DEVELOPER_DIR /Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer
    setenv LEX /Developer/usr/bin/lex
    setenv LIBRARY_FLAG_NOSPACE YES
    setenv LIBRARY_FLAG_PREFIX -l
    setenv LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS "\"/Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos\" "
    setenv LINKER_DISPLAYS_MANGLED_NAMES NO
    setenv LINK_FILE_LIST_normal_armv7 /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Intermediates/Serenity.build/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Serenity.LinkFileList
    setenv LINK_WITH_STANDARD_LIBRARIES YES
    setenv LOCAL_ADMIN_APPS_DIR /Applications/Utilities
    setenv LOCAL_APPS_DIR /Applications
    setenv LOCAL_DEVELOPER_DIR /Library/Developer
    setenv LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIR /Library
    setenv MACH_O_TYPE staticlib
    setenv MAC_OS_X_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 10K549
    setenv MAC_OS_X_VERSION_ACTUAL 1068
    setenv MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAJOR 1060
    setenv MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MINOR 0608
    setenv NATIVE_ARCH armv7
    setenv NATIVE_ARCH_32_BIT i386
    setenv NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT x86_64
    setenv NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL x86_64
    setenv NO_COMMON YES
    setenv OBJECT_FILE_DIR /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Intermediates/Serenity.build/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.build/Objects
    setenv OBJECT_FILE_DIR_normal /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Intermediates/Serenity.build/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.build/Objects-normal
    setenv OBJROOT /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Intermediates
    setenv ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH NO
    setenv OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL 0
    setenv OS MACOS
    setenv OSAC /usr/bin/osacompile
    setenv OTHER_LDFLAGS -ObjC
    setenv PACKAGE_TYPE com.apple.package-type.static-library
    setenv PASCAL_STRINGS YES
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PATH_PREFIXES_EXCLUDED_FROM_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES "/usr/include /usr/local/include /System/Library/Frameworks /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks /Developer/Headers /Developer/SDKs /Developer/Platforms"
    setenv PFE_FILE_C_DIALECTS objective-c
    setenv PKGINFO_FILE_PATH /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Intermediates/Serenity.build/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.build/PkgInfo
    setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Applications
    setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin
    setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR /Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library
    setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs
    setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Tools
    setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr
    setenv PLATFORM_DIR /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
    setenv PLATFORM_NAME iphoneos
    setenv PLATFORM_PREFERRED_ARCH armv7
    setenv PLATFORM_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 9A334
    setenv PLIST_FILE_OUTPUT_FORMAT binary
    setenv PRECOMPS_INCLUDE_HEADERS_FROM_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR YES
    setenv PRECOMP_DESTINATION_DIR /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Intermediates/Serenity.build/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.build/PrefixHeaders
    setenv PRESERVE_DEAD_CODE_INITS_AND_TERMS NO
    setenv PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH /usr/local/include
    setenv PRODUCT_NAME Serenity
    setenv PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH 
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.library.static
    setenv PROFILING_CODE NO
    setenv PROJECT Serenity
    setenv PROJECT_DERIVED_FILE_DIR /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Intermediates/Serenity.build/DerivedSources
    setenv PROJECT_DIR /Users/manoj/Desktop/Serenity
    setenv PROJECT_FILE_PATH /Users/manoj/Desktop/Serenity/Serenity.xcodeproj
    setenv PROJECT_NAME Serenity
    setenv PROJECT_TEMP_DIR /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Intermediates/Serenity.build
    setenv RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATHS_FOLLOW_SYMLINKS YES
    setenv REMOVE_CVS_FROM_RESOURCES YES
    setenv REMOVE_GIT_FROM_RESOURCES YES
    setenv REMOVE_HG_FROM_RESOURCES YES
    setenv REMOVE_SVN_FROM_RESOURCES YES
    setenv REZ_COLLECTOR_DIR /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Intermediates/Serenity.build/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.build/ResourceManagerResources
    setenv REZ_EXECUTABLE YES
    setenv REZ_OBJECTS_DIR /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Intermediates/Serenity.build/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.build/ResourceManagerResources/Objects
    setenv REZ_SEARCH_PATHS "\"/Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos\" "
    setenv RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER NO
    setenv SCAN_ALL_SOURCE_FILES_FOR_INCLUDES NO
    setenv SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_COUNT 0
    setenv SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_COUNT 0
    setenv SDKROOT /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk
    setenv SDK_DIR /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk
    setenv SDK_NAME iphoneos5.0
    setenv SDK_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 9A334
    setenv SED /usr/bin/sed
    setenv SEPARATE_STRIP YES
    setenv SEPARATE_SYMBOL_EDIT NO
    setenv SET_DIR_MODE_OWNER_GROUP YES
    setenv SET_FILE_MODE_OWNER_GROUP NO
    setenv SHARED_DERIVED_FILE_DIR /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DerivedSources
    setenv SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/PrecompiledHeaders
    setenv SKIP_INSTALL YES
    setenv SOURCE_ROOT /Users/manoj/Desktop/Serenity
    setenv SRCROOT /Users/manoj/Desktop/Serenity
    setenv STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING binary
    setenv STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT YES
    setenv STRIP_STYLE non-global
    setenv SUPPORTED_DEVICE_FAMILIES 1,2
    setenv SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS "iphonesimulator iphoneos"
    setenv SYMROOT /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products
    setenv SYSTEM_ADMIN_APPS_DIR /Applications/Utilities
    setenv SYSTEM_APPS_DIR /Applications
    setenv SYSTEM_CORE_SERVICES_DIR /System/Library/CoreServices
    setenv SYSTEM_DEMOS_DIR /Applications/Extras
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_APPS_DIR /Developer/Applications
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR /Developer/usr/bin
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DEMOS_DIR "/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Built Examples"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR /Developer
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DOC_DIR "/Developer/ADC Reference Library"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_GRAPHICS_TOOLS_DIR "/Developer/Applications/Graphics Tools"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_JAVA_TOOLS_DIR "/Developer/Applications/Java Tools"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_PERFORMANCE_TOOLS_DIR "/Developer/Applications/Performance Tools"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_RELEASENOTES_DIR "/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS /Developer/Tools
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DOC_DIR "/Developer/ADC Reference Library/documentation/DeveloperTools"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_RELEASENOTES_DIR "/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes/DeveloperTools"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR /Developer/usr
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_UTILITIES_DIR /Developer/Applications/Utilities
    setenv SYSTEM_DOCUMENTATION_DIR /Library/Documentation
    setenv SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR /System/Library
    setenv TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY 1
    setenv TARGETNAME Serenity
    setenv TARGET_BUILD_DIR /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
    setenv TARGET_NAME Serenity
    setenv TARGET_TEMP_DIR /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Intermediates/Serenity.build/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.build
    setenv TEMP_DIR /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Intermediates/Serenity.build/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.build
    setenv TEMP_FILES_DIR /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Intermediates/Serenity.build/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.build
    setenv TEMP_FILE_DIR /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Intermediates/Serenity.build/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.build
    setenv TEMP_ROOT /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Intermediates
    setenv TEST_AFTER_BUILD NO
    setenv UID 501
    setenv UNSTRIPPED_PRODUCT NO
    setenv USER manoj
    setenv USER_APPS_DIR /Users/manoj/Applications
    setenv USER_LIBRARY_DIR /Users/manoj/Library
    setenv USE_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC YES
    setenv USE_HEADERMAP YES
    setenv USE_HEADER_SYMLINKS NO
    setenv VALIDATE_PRODUCT NO
    setenv VALID_ARCHS "armv6 armv7"
    setenv VERBOSE_PBXCP NO
    setenv VERSION_INFO_BUILDER manoj
    setenv VERSION_INFO_FILE Serenity_vers.c
    setenv VERSION_INFO_STRING "\"@(#)PROGRAM:Serenity  PROJECT:Serenity-4.3.2\""
    setenv XCODE_APP_SUPPORT_DIR /Developer/Library/Xcode
    setenv XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 4C199
    setenv XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL 0420
    setenv XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR 0400
    setenv XCODE_VERSION_MINOR 0420
    setenv YACC /Developer/usr/bin/yacc
    /bin/sh -c /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Intermediates/Serenity.build/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.build/Script-AF9704D4171D31C2007A7DCE.sh

cp: /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers: name too long (not copied)
cp: /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/.DS_Store: name too long (not copied)
cp: /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/libSerenity.a: name too long (not copied)
cp: /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/mathfunc.h: name too long (not copied)
cp: /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework: name too long (not copied)
cp: /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Headers: name too long (not copied)
cp: /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Serenity: name too long (not copied)
cp: /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions: name too long (not copied)
cp: /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A: name too long (not copied)
cp: /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A: name too long (not copied)
cp: /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions: name too long (not copied)
cp: /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework: name too long (not copied)
cp: /Users/manoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serenity-guqdsmsjkaeyodcpcowssogdpfoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Serenity.framework/Versions/A/Headers: name too long (not copied)
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1


please Help me


thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `${PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH}` *should* contain, but according to the output, this variable is undefined or empty. Therefore this

```
cp -a "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH}/" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/Headers"
```

is actually

```
cp -a "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/Headers"
```

You copy the BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR into a subdirectory of itself, causing a recursion
during the copy process and a *very deep*
directory structure which ultimately exceeds the longest allowed path names.

Comment: sir i changed the command...but error is same..what should i do now

Comment: @yash: What did you change? I cannot guess it!

Comment: sir i replace  cp -a "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH}/" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/Headers"  to   cp -a "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/Headers" but error is same

Comment: @yash: Yes of course! Again you copy BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR into a subdirectory of itself! The first argument to "cp -a" should be the path to the headers that you want to copy.

Answer (score 0):

The cp command failed because the file names are too long (just look at the right hand end of your log file entries).  It looks as if you've got some kind of recursion going on in your variables and I think it is your symbolic links that are causing the problem.

Try running your script like this...

```
bash -x <your_shell _script>
```

and examine the logs again - it should give you a clue.

Comment: cp -a "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/Headers"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't have to edit anything in the shell script directly. Working from within Xcode, I accidentally toggled / deleted the values of two target property settings in the Info panel. Recreating them made this error go away. Reverting to a previous version of the application on git didn't fix this, interestingly. Luckily I had another copy of the file to refer to.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Public Headers and add "include/". Should resolve the symlink issues.